# Dynamically Loading Compiled Libraries in CHICKEN-Scheme

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

I would like to know, if it is possible, the best way to dynamically load compiled code in CHICKEN-Scheme. The API states `load` only loads source files.

Specifically my goal in dynamically loading code is to be able to overwrite previously defined functions. That is `foo` in library 1 would get replaced by a different `foo` in library 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Unit%20eval#load) for `load` says

> On platforms that support it (currently BSD, Haiku, MacOS X, Linux, Solaris, and Windows), load can be used to load compiled programs

This means you *can* actually load `.so` files with `load`.  Replacing an identifier is possible, by simply `set!`ting it to a different value.

If you want to dynamically load code from arbitrary directories, I think `load` is your best bet.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! It is annoying that one part of the documentation says something different from [another.](http://api.call-cc.org/doc/scheme/load) For those wandering in, I first compiled `lib-1.ss` to c with `csc -t lib-1.ss` and then compiled the `.so` file with `gcc -shared lib-1.so -fPIC lib-1.c` There is one annoying restriction on loading `.so` files: "A compiled file can only be loaded once. Subsequent attempts to load the same file have no effect." However as you said, I can work around this with `set!`

Comment: Typo that was noticed too late: `gcc -shared -o lib-1.so -fPIC lib-1.c`

Comment: You're right about the inconsistency in the docs.  The "scheme" part is copied from R5RS, which is why it says that.  We'll have to fix that...